# Closing an NSOutputstream & NSInputstream

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to interrupt

```
[NSOutputstream write]
```

when the connection is lost.

However, it seems that it continues to block even though I close the stream using

```
[NSOutputstream close].
```

All I'm trying to achieve is reconnection when the server connection is lost.

I tried to schedule a NSTimer before the send call - What it does is close the stream if the send call did not manage to finish within the interval (Something like 5 seconds) but the close operation does not affect the stream at all. It continues to block. Sigh.

How can I implement a auto-reconnection to the server in case of disconnection?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do with streams is to register them on the threads run loop using [scheduleInRunLoop:forMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSStream/scheduleInRunLoop:forMode:) and deal with the delegate events which are raised telling you when there is capacity to write, when there is data to read and when there are errors.

This way you are efficiently interacting with the network stack and when you detect an error through the delegate events, you can reconnect and add the new streams to the run loop.

NB: Calling close will remove the stream from the run loop.